# \chapter and \chapter* layout

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm trying to write some notes and I changed the `\chapter` layout in a separate cls class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClassWithOptions{book}


\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{eucal}
\RequirePackage[tracking=true,spacing=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\SetTracking{encoding=*,shape=sc}{0}


%this is my attempt to change chapter layout
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
\fontsize{13.5pt}{14.5pt}%
\usefont{T1}{cmbright}{m}{n}%
\raggedright%
}%
\item%
\thechapter\par\vskip 23.5pt plus 12pt minus 6.5pt%
#1\par\vskip -6pt\hrulefill
\end{list}%
\vskip 12.7mm plus 4mm minus 4mm}


% some packages
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{mathdots}
\RequirePackage{bigdelim}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\RequirePackage{chappg}
```

after reading the [book.cls](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) user manual the code above was the best I could do. The problem is that this code do not change the layout of `\chapter*`. Here is an example

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Blah}
blah blah blah

\chapter*{Foo}
blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]
for `\chapter{Blah}`, and this
[image]
for `\chapter*{Foo}`. So I want to know how can I change the layout for `\chapter*`

Thanks in advance

Comment: just do the same with `\@makeschapterhead`  (note the `s`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle simple and accurate! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same with `\@makeschapterhead` (note the `s`)